# Error after packaging the app with electron-packager

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I'm new to Electron, and I really love it so far, but I'm unable to package any of mine apps, at first I thought that it's maybe something related to my code, then I download "https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start" run npm install and then I run "electron-packager . FooBar --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.28.2" it build the app but when I try to open it I get

[image]

so I didn't touch any code from the example, just wanted to build it and I got an error, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The versions of electron are moving very very fast.
And some times, they don't respect the "old" ways to do things (for example, declaring the app).

I advise you to not use the 0.28.2 version of electron but the most recent one.

Comment: That was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the version of `electron-prebuilt` you are using to develop is much much much more recent than the `0.28.2` version. So, you are developing with something much newer, and then you are building with `0.28.2`. This would cause the exact error that you are seeing, as older versions may not have had the electron module, which your code explicitly is importing. So... that is my suggestion. Change the version in your `electron-packager` command from `0.28.2` to something like `0.36.0`. See if that works. Or better yet, use the same version as `electron-prebuilt` in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a combination of factors.

First, as others stated, the version of electron that you have might be newer than the one referenced in your build command. Locate the 'electron_prebuilt' folder inside your 'node_modules' folder, and examine the package.json file and make sure the version # is the same as what you are declaring in your build command.

If they are the same, then the issue might be that you have another version of electron on your computer that node is trying to use. If you installed electron via the -g option (global), check your home folder to see if there is another different version of electron. If you find one, either delete it or rename the 'electron_prebuilt' folder you find to something else. Try your build command again, and it should work now that you've eliminated the other versions of electron_prebuilt on your computer that node was referencing.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to move the "electron" module from "dev-dependencies" to "dependencies" in package.json. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: Funny, what worked for me was moving it from "dependencies" to "dev-dependencies" !