# After building Ionic production, Electron gives: Cannot find module "."

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, electron, ionic3, electron-builder

We have a legacy Ionic app on v3 we need to support still.  We're upgrading to Ionic 5+Angular of this app, but until that is ready, we need to support the older one.

We've been able to successfully build and package this app before wiping the 'node_modules' on two machines.  Now, we cannot get a production build to work with Electron.

This works, electron opens and loads the app fine:

```
1. ionic-app-scripts build
2. electron .
```

This does not work:

```
1. ionic-app-scripts build --prod
2. electron .
```

Electron opens, but in console gives:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at vendor.js:1
    at vendor.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:1)
    at e (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
    at e (vendor.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
    at main.js:1
```

This happens with 'electron-builder' as well.  The created application gives the same error.

What I've tried:

1. Different versions of npm/Node installed on computer
2. Rebuilding node-sass
3. Different versions of electron-builder
4. Non-production build of app, electron-builder packed, packaged app opens and works fine
5. Commented 'return optimizedProdLoaders;' line in @ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js (Goal was to match production to dev build as much as possible).  Result same.

I can't find anything out on the internet about this particular error. Most I can find is the console gives which module name it cannot fine which helps you track this down.

The error "Cannot find module '.'" we're getting is the most useless error to track down what's happening.  I'm tempted to just roll with a non-production version.

Comment: See if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022252/316459

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately same results.  Is there a way to build production but toggle off the minification/uglify of the code?  I can put a breakpoint where it errors in the vendor.js but I can't make any sense of it.